# Is EJB Timer Service Thread safe?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

Is EJB Timer Service Thread Safe? 
When multithreads call to create timerservice, and then use their own timerservice to create 
timer. How the jboss container queue these events and kick off the timer?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, it is still a current concern.
I think you're probably referring to concurrency among timer services running in a multiserver environment, as thread safety usually refers to processes running on the same JVM, and solved through synchronized methods.

In a multiserver environment, if you don't want the same EJB Timers to be triggered concurrently at exactly the same scheduled times, it is possible to store them in a shared resource (e.g. a database) and orderly trigger them on some of the servers, without interference to/from the others.

The main approach seems to be defining persistent EJB Timers and a datasource with *serializable transaction isolation*, so only one server at a time will be able to update the timers schedule control table. Based on that, I see two possible approaches:

1. Timer service enabled JBoss servers configured to run in a cluster, so the EJB Timers will only be triggered on one node at a time (i.e. a single execution of the timer). [1]
2. On a non-clustered environment, maybe you could select a server to have EJB Timer execution enabled, and disable that execution on the other servers.

This is certainly not a thorough list of all possibilities, but I think it might be a starting point to configure EJB Timers in a multiserver envivonment.

**references:**

[1]: JBoss - Mastering the Boss - Creating clustered EJB 3 Timers 
     - http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/creating-clustered-ejb-3-timers

[2]: JBoss - Mastering the Boss - Configuring WildFly Batch Job Repository 
     - http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/configuring-wildfly-batch-job-repository

[3]: StackOverFlow - [How to disable Timer service in Wildfly 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027870/how-to-disable-timer-service-in-wildfly-10#37217794)