# How to disable Timer service in Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, wildfly

In my Java EE application I have a `@Singleton` with several `@Schedule`d methods. When I deploy the app on Wildfly, the Timer service starts executing these methods, which is correct.

Since during development I test my app on a secondary server, I'd like to disable the Timer service on that instance of Wildfly, to prevent the execution of those methods.

Problem is… I can't find any setting to do this.

How can I disable the Timer service in Wildfly 10?

Comment: http://jdevelopment.nl/disabling-ejb-timers-java-ee-6/

Comment: Thank you Cassio, but I would prefer to disable the service than having a second application to cancel each invocation of scheduled methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove block `timer-service` in standalone.xml.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:3.0">
...
<timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
```

It works for wildfly 9.